# CPU not reaching turbo frequency under load

Tags: linux, cpu, performance, cpu-usage, turbo-boost

I have this cpu (output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`)

```
processor   : 15
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x49
cpu MHz     : 2956.072
cache size  : 20480 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 8
core id     : 7
cpu cores   : 8
apicid      : 30
initial apicid  : 30
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 15
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm xsaveopt cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc dtherm ida arat pln pts
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 4800.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Hardware limit is 3.2 Ghz in turbo mode (as shown by `cpupower`):

```
analyzing CPU 15:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 15
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 15
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 3.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 3.20 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 2.85 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

I created a small script to generate high load on one core and check its frequency with `cpupower -c 15 frequency-info -f -m`, it indeed reaches 3.2 Ghz.

However, when running the script on all cores, the frequency of each core is capped at 2.6 Ghz somehow.

Where is the bottleneck ? power management policy is in `performance` everywhere.

Comment: According to [Intel arc database](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/64593/intel-xeon-processor-e52630-15m-cache-2-30-ghz-7-20-gts-intel-qpi/specifications.html) your CPU has a Max Turbo Frequency 2.80 GHz. If it does not reach that limit most likely power or temperature limit are already exceeded (e.g. because of multiple used cores).

Comment: Must be temperature then. The database is wrong though or it's not the same CPU, I can successfully reach 3.2 GHz on one core as stated in my post